# Laravel Eloquent: access method parameter within chunk Closure

Tags: php, laravel, static, scope, eloquent

I need to pass an anonymous function to a static method on an Eloquent model and have that static method call the closure within a chunk closure. The goal is code similar to the following:

```
class MyModel extends Eloquent {
    // ... table stuff
    public static function doSomething (Closure $thing) {
        $dispatcher = static::getEventDispatcher();
        static::unsetEventDispatcher();
        static::chunk(100, function ($records) {
            foreach($records as $model) {
                $thing($model); // not set in this scope
            }
        });
        static::setEventDispatcher($dispatcher);
    }
}
//...
MyModel::doSomething(function($m){/*some crypto stuff*/});
```

`$thing` is not set because it is out of scope. I am wondering if there is some trick to make this work. Currently, I am using a non-static method and am calling chunk around the closure represented by `$thing`:

```
class MyModel extends Eloquent {
    public function doSomething (Closure $thing) {
        // unset event dispatcher
        $thing($this);
        // reset event dispatcher
    }
}

MyModel::chunk(100, function ($records) {
    foreach($records as $model) {
        $model->doSomething(function($m){/*some crypto stuff*/});
    }
}
```

This is suboptimal as I have to write the chunk loop every time I want to call `doSomething` and the event dispatcher is removed and reset for every record (or even worse: I'd have to remember to deal with the event dispatcher before calling `chunk`, at which point I may as well not even try to consolidate my code).

Anyone know of any tricks that could make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `use` keyword allow the anonymous function to inherit variables from the parent scope.

```
class MyModel extends Eloquent {
    // ... table stuff
    public static function doSomething (Closure $thing) {
        $dispatcher = static::getEventDispatcher();
        static::unsetEventDispatcher();
        // note the use keyword
        static::chunk(100, function ($records) use ($thing) {
            foreach($records as $model) {
                $thing($model); // not set in this scope
            }
        });
        static::setEventDispatcher($dispatcher);
    }
}
```

Anonymous function documentation [here](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php). The `use` keyword is shown in example 3.

Comment: _gives you a jar of cookies_

I totally forgot about that.